# Showing a Query to Excel in VBA Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have this table:

[image: Table]

And I did the next query that works for sure:

```sql
SELECT tbl_Type.Id_Type, 
tbl_Type.Info, 
tbl_Type.Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info, 
tbl_Type.DateX

FROM tbl_Type

WHERE (((tbl_Type.DateX)=[Write Date (dd/dd/yyy)]));
```

As you see in the query in the `WHERE` part there's an input of the column DateX.

Now I want to use same procedure but using a form for the input, the code to do that is this:

```vb
Private Sub btn_Action_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    
    Dim Fecha As String
    
    Fecha = _
    "SELECT tbl_Type.Id_Type, tbl_Type.Info, tbl_Type.Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info, tbl_Type.DateX FROM tbl_Type WHERE tbl_Type.DateX = txt_Date.value;"

    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef ([Nom],Fecha) As QueryDef
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL Fecha
    'DoCmd.Save Fecha, "s"
    
    txt_Date = Null
    
End Sub
```

First, I want to know if it is well performed the input in the content of the String `Fecha`. As you see I'm giving that action when the button `btn_Action` is clicked and capturing the input for DateX with a Text Field `txt_Date` I would say that the query is working but I don't know how to see that, in that order I proceed to pretend to save that query, which is something desired too. I've seen in another question that for do that is used `CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef` I tried `DoCmd.Save` but I think that isn't the case. With `CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef` I'm having a syntax error. Am I missing something?

Please, if more details are needed, still is a silly question or things like that let me now, to do the correct procedure!

Comment: What do you want to do with query after taking the date value?

Comment: Now that you say that, It won't be correct, I guess, to save a table, since what I want is to keep that query result on an Excel woorkbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simply saving a parameterized query and then in VBA bind your form value to parameter using [QueryDef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845129.aspx) object. MS Access SQL maintains the `PARAMETERS` clause to set named placeholders. Below outputs parameterized query results to Excel workbook.

**SQL** *(save below as a query, Ribbon > Create > Query Design > SQL View)*

```sql
PARAMETERS DateParam Datetime;
SELECT t.Id_Type, 
       t.Info, 
       t.Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info, 
       t.DateX    
FROM tbl_Type t    
WHERE (((t.DateX)=[DateParam]));
```

**VBA** *(calls query, bind parameters, export to new Excel workbook)*

```vb
Private Sub btn_Action_Click()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
    Dim xl_app As Object, xl_wb As Objcect
    Dim qdef As QueryDef, rst As Recordset

    ' REFERENCE SAVED QUERY
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDef("mySavedQuery")

    ' BIND PARAMETER
    qdef!DateParam = txt_Date

    ' SET qdef TO RECORDSET
    Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()

    ' EXPORT TO EXCEL
    Set xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xl_wb = xl_app.Workbooks.Add()

    With xl_wb.Sheets(1)
       ' COLUMNS
       For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
          .Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
       Next i 

       ' DATA
      .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End With

    xl_app.Visible = True

    txt_Date = Null

ExitHandle:
   rst.Close()
   Set rst = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing
   Set xl_wb = Nothing: Set xl_app = Nothing
   Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
   Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
   Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time with this, there's a lot of useful things in here, very helpfull, Thank you!

Comment: The column names aren't being displayed, is there any similar property to Recordset to fill in the workbook the column names?

Comment: See updated for columns iterating through recordset's field names.

Comment: Yes, now is displaying the columns name very well, thanks! Can you explain something about `DateParam` in the part of bind the parameter, I mean, why that word?

Comment: You can name it anything just as long as the name used in the SQL query, `PARAMETERS ...` clause aligns with the QueryDef item with `qdef! ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the value of the input to your query string like so

```
Fecha = _
"SELECT tbl_Type.Id_Type, tbl_Type.Info, tbl_Type.Id_Table_Three_Plus_Info, tbl_Type.DateX FROM tbl_Type WHERE tbl_Type.DateX = " & txt_Date.value & ";"
```

To inspect the result, you should execute in debug mode (Press F8 instead of F5 in vba).

Comment: *You have to concatenate the value* ... Do note: MS Access supports parameterization.